# name 'bpy' is undefined

Tags: python

In `test.py` I have the following line. It was taken from [this page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Advanced_Tutorials/Python_Scripting/Introduction):

```
bpy.data.objects
```

Then I start blender from the bash prompt:

```
blender Rigged\ Hand.blend  --python test.py
```

The response on the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sam/proj/Rigged Hand/a/setup.py", line 1, in <module>
    bpy.data.objects
NameError: name 'bpy' is not defined
```

Even though blender has opened my file, I can open the python prompt inside blender and type the same thing; I get the response `<bpy_collection[5], BlendDataObjects>` as expected.

Why can I not use bpy in the script which I invoked from the command line?

Comment: You have to "import bpy" first.

Comment: @Doyousketch2 Okay, that was unobvious, because you don't have to `import bpy` from the python console inside Blender. But post it as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"import bpy" first.

They automatically import that module in the console as a convenience,
so you don't have to type it in every time.  -cheers